# A recent 14.04 update broke a java app

Tags: openjdk

The app that broke is an older Adaptec Storage Manager (v4.30), which has worked faithfully for years now until a recent Ubuntu 14.04 update.

The best I can tell is that the problem occurred when `openjdk-7-jdk` was updated, but I am not sure which Java version worked correctly with the Adaptec Storage Manager. For quite some time, all Javas worked with this version on Ubuntu.

The error when launching the app is:

```
java objectinputstream filter check rejected
```

The class in question is `java.net.inetaddress`.

The nature of the problem is that this app attempts to authenticate the user before allowing access to the host controller management functions.  As I recall, guest privileges were fine for this, but it seems that the authentication module itself is failing to execute.

I am aware of the `java.security` file for the various Java versions as well as the policy editors, but I am not sure what would work to correct this.

What would be helpful is knowing for sure which `openjdk` build was working before this all happened, but I do not know where to get that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is a very old post now, but since I have the answer, I thought it would be helpful to follow up.

For any of the OpenJDK or Oracle java versions, updating java.security as shown below will correct one of the issues with using the Adaptec Storage Manager for the 2410SA raid controller under Linux.

Change

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, EC keySize < 224
```

to remove the `RC4`:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, EC keySize < 224
```

The other significant required changes to java.security are:

```
jdk.serialFilter=*
sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter=*
sun.rmi.transport.dgcFilter=\
java.rmi.server.ObjID;\
java.rmi.server.UID;\
java.rmi.dgc.VMID;\
java.rmi.dgc.Lease;\
maxdepth=5;maxarray=10000
```

I tested these changes with Ubuntu 14.04.5 and 16.04.3.

As a side note: 
OpenJDK `7u151-2.6.11-0ubuntu1.14.04.1` and `7u151-2.6.11-1+deb7u1`
do not require the change to `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`.

Since the Adaptec Storage Manager version I am using is old (`asm_linux_v4.30-16038.rpm`), and is no longer supported at that version, 
changing the java.security file was my only option aside from the arcconf command line utility which works fine either way.

Perhaps this post will help somebody some day.